# Updating live chart within tkinter, plot shows but doesn't run update function either once or repeatedly

Tags: user-interface, matplotlib, tkinter, bar-chart, live-streaming

OrbGuiClass creates a tkinter gui with two static candlestick charts.  The data is pulled from csvs which is why code won't run for you.  The third chart is a top-level chart which I want to be live and it works on its own outside of a canvas, GUI, etc but with the GUI FuncAnimation not running.  I have seen examples where it's outside of the class but this doesn't work either.

```
class OrbGuiClass:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root=root
        self.frame1=tk.Frame(root)
        self.day_data=[self.dt,self.o,self.h,self.l,self.c]
        self.tenwty_four=[self.ddt,self.oo,self.hh,self.ll,self.cc]
        self.create_canvas()
        self.create_live_canvas()
        self.frame1.grid(row=4,column=2)
    def create_canvas(self):
        self.fig=Figure(figsize=(8,4))
        self.ax1=self.fig.add_subplot(121,title='24 Hour Chart')
        self.ax2=self.fig.add_subplot(122,title='Day Chart')
        candlestick2_ochl(self.ax1,self.oo[9:len(self.oo)],
        self.hh[9:len(self.hh)],self.ll[9:len(self.ll)],
        self.cc[9:len(self.cc)])
        candlestick2_ochl(self.ax2,self.o,self.h,self.l,self.c)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=root)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1,column=0,    
        columnspan=2,rowspan=2,sticky="ne")
        self.canvas.show()
    def create_live_canvas(self):
        toplevel = tk.Toplevel()
        self.fig2=Figure(figsize=(4,4), dpi=100)
        self.ax=self.fig2.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig2, toplevel)
        self.canvas2.show()
        self.canvas2.get_tk_widget().pack()
        self.anim=animation.FuncAnimation
        (self.fig2,self.update,frames=100,interval=25)
    def update(self, dummy):
        #get_data() is a web crawling function that returns OHLC values
        O,H,L,C= get_data()
        self.ax=plt.gca()
        self.ax.clear()
        self.ax.set_xlim([-.5,.5])
        candlestick2_ohlc(self.ax,O,H,L,C,width=.2,
        colorup='g',colordown='r',alpha=1.0)

root = tk.Tk()
app=OrbGuiClass(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Before you animate it, you should place and display the figure canvas in the GUI. Right now, you have some of the parts for a bicycle, and are asking how to build a Ferrari. Your code doesn't run as is, making it hard to help you.

Comment: Seeing the code, I don't see why it shouldn't work as it is. Therefore the problem itself is not really clear. Because the code also is no [mcve], it's not really possible to judge on potential sources of failure. To stay in the picture, you're bringing your Ford to the workshop without wheels and ask if the problem is with the engine.

Comment: Ok I see the Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example recs and will update code to reproduce the problem.  Makes sense. Am new to this so please excuse me.

Answer (score 0):

The only work around I can come up with to get this to work is to create a separate figure above the class using plt.figure() and running FuncAnimation below and then plt.show().  Also in order for this to work you need to include toplevel=tk.Toplevel() at top of the program and the gui will display in multiple windows.  So now I have a taped together bike, but I was dreaming of a Ferrari.  Ah reality.  Make sure you put plt.figure() where I put it and Toplevel() below root=tk.Tk() and app=OrbGuiClass(root) because other wise your guy will be separated.

```
class OrbGuiClass:
    def __init__(self,root):

    def create_canvas(self):
        self.fig=Figure(figsize=(8,4))

root = tk.Tk()
app=OrbGuiClass(root)

toplevel=tk.Toplevel()

fig2=plt.figure()
ax=fig2.add_subplot(111)
def update(dummy):
    O,H,L,C= get_data()
    ax=plt.gca()
    ax.clear()
    ax.set_xlim([-.5,.5])
    candlestick2_ohlc(ax,O,H,L,C,width=.2,
    colorup='g',colordown='r',alpha=1.0)
ani=animation.FuncAnimation(fig2,update,frames=100,interval=3000)
plt.show()
root.mainloop()
```